# Dell 7537 syslog over 40 GB

Tags: kernel, hard-drive, users, disk-usage, syslog

I am a new user and not a techie, but i love ubuntu. I am at 14.10 currently and have almost 60GB allocated to `/var` but lately the `/var` folder has been eating up almost over 40GB of space, the last few lines of syslog are:

```
Mar 30 19:39:43 asad-Inspiron-7537 kernel: [ 2839.453308] smo8800 SMO8810:00: detected free fall
Mar 30 19:39:43 asad-Inspiron-7537 kernel: [ 2839.453323] smo8800 SMO8810:00: detected free fall
Mar 30 19:39:43 asad-Inspiron-7537 kernel: [ 2839.453343] smo8800 SMO8810:00: detected free fall
Mar 30 19:39:43 asad-Inspiron-7537 kernel: [ 2839.453360] smo8800 SMO8810:00: detected free fall
Mar 30 19:39:43 asad-Inspiron-7537 kernel: [ 2839.453374] smo8800 SMO8810:00: detected free fall
Mar 30 19:39:43 asad-Inspiron-7537 kernel: [ 2839.453390] smo8800 SMO8810:00: detected free fall
Mar 30 19:39:43 asad-Inspiron-7537 kernel: [ 2839.453403] smo8800 SMO8810:00: detected free fall
Mar 30 19:39:43 asad-Inspiron-7537 kernel: [ 2839.453419] smo8800 SMO8810:00: detected free fall
Mar 30 19:39:43 asad-Inspiron-7537 kernel: [ 2839.453434] smo8800 SMO8810:00: detected free fall
Mar 30 19:39:43 asad-Inspiron-7537 kernel: [ 2839.453450] smo8800 SMO8810:00: detected free fall
asad@asad-Inspiron
```

Researching a bit more lead me to a deamon by Jesse Sung which is supposed to solve the issue but it hasn't or maybe i am not doing things correctly.

The hard drive still keeps writing the same line over and over again into syslog and kern.log file and the system is very laggy and HD almost full. Please let me know how to solve this issue.

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with `logrotate`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is a free fall sensor, (accelerometer)
whether it is failing, or giving erroneous data, I'm not sure. 
I recomend you black list the free fall sensor, and depending on how critical your hard disk drive space is, delete or clear the syslog file as well.

```
sudo  > /var/adm/sylog
```

I am suspicious that there is another issue as well, that logs should never reach 40GB in size. As in, why hasn't logrotate done its job, and rotate the logs? that is likely a separate question. On to blacklisting your hardware, to prevent the logging of its errors.

do sudo lspci -k
and look through there to identify the part which is giving you the warnings.
you can also look at lsmod, and try to figure out the module givng this error from there.
Once you have figured out the correct module, you will edit the /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf file.
youll do `sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and add a line that says:

blacklist free_fall_module

after that, save and close, then reboot. you shouldn't get the errors in syslog any more.

Comment: Thank you so much, your suggestion worked perfectly. The module was **dell_smo8800** so i added it in the blacklist.conf and now there are no new similar log entries in the syslog. Thanks.